# Is there a way to merge signatures from a decorator and wrapped function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm looking to wrap a callable with a decorator taking an additional parameter, with the signature of the wrapped function as the union of the two.

For example

```
def decorator(func):
    # something like @functools.wrap 
    def wrapper(other_param: int = None, **kwargs):
        pass

    return wrapper

@decorator
def myfunc(*, foo: int, bar: int):
    pass
```

What I would like is a way to call `inspect.signature` on decorated myfunc and get all three named params. I am aware of the sigtools library but cannot use it as a dependency.

Edit: To clarify, I want the signature of wrapper to be (foo, bar, other_param).

Comment: Do you want ``**kwargs`` of ``wrapper`` to become ``*, foo, bar``, or just the *signature* of ``wrapper`` to pretend it takes ``*, foo, bar``?

Comment: can't you check out the code of sigtools and copy the part that you want?

Comment: sigtools uses a lot of abstraction and there's hopefully a lot cleaner way than re-implementing the library

Comment: The signature of your wrapped function *isn't* `foo, bar, other_param`, so reporting it as such would be wrong; it's effectively `other_param=None, *, foo, bar`. I've used [the `decorator` package](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/) for stuff like this before, though only to preserve a signature, not to expand it.